# if possible to compare with two dates in already inserted documents ,without enter query data (

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV7q4.png)data range between dispatch time to disposal time

I'm tried `await Product.find({ $and: [ { disposalTime:{ $lte:new Date().toISOString()} }, { dispatchTime: { $gte:new Date().toISOString()} } ]})`

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare with `$$NOW` in a `$expr`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $lte: [
          "$disposalTime",
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      },
      {
        $gte: [
          "$dispatchTime",
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qeeSkoYAR7u)